# Python group list element by value into tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, grouping

I have this list:

```
mylist = ['*', 'Drama', 'Film Noir', 'Mystery', 'Romance', '*', 'Dance', 'Drama', 'Musical', '*', 'Crime', 'Drama', '*', 'Action', 'Drama', 'Period', 'Western', '*', 'Adaptation', 'Based-on', 'Comedy', 'Romance', '*', 'Mystery', 'Thriller', '*', 'Comedy']
```

Obviously, the element ' * ' is separating groups within the list. How do I group the occurrence of elements in between ' * '? The desired result will look like this:

```
expected_list = [('Drama', 'Film Noir', 'Mystery', 'Romance'), ('Dance', 'Drama', 'Musical'), ('Crime', 'Drama'), ('Action', 'Drama', 'Period', 'Western'), ('Adaptation', 'Based-on', 'Comedy', 'Romance'), ('Mystery', 'Thriller'), ('Comedy')]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic [use case for `itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

expected_list = [tuple(grp) for isstar, grp in groupby(mylist, key='*'.__eq__) if not isstar]
```

That groups your inputs into runs of `*` and not-`*`, drops the `*` groups, and `tuple`s up the non-`*` groups.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group entries by whether they are `*` or not and then just keep those parts that are not `*` using the `__ne__` (not equal) method or an equivalent `lambda` expression:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> mylist = ['*', 'Drama', 'Film Noir', 'Mystery', 'Romance', '*', 'Dance', 'Drama', 'Musical', '*', 'Crime', 'Drama', '*', 'Action', 'Drama', 'Period', 'Western', '*', 'Adaptation', 'Based-on', 'Comedy', 'Romance', '*', 'Mystery', 'Thriller', '*', 'Comedy']
>>> [tuple(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(mylist, key="*".__ne__) if k]
[('Drama', 'Film Noir', 'Mystery', 'Romance'),
 ('Dance', 'Drama', 'Musical'),
 ('Crime', 'Drama'),
 ('Action', 'Drama', 'Period', 'Western'),
 ('Adaptation', 'Based-on', 'Comedy', 'Romance'),
 ('Mystery', 'Thriller'),
 ('Comedy',)]
```